# Why Files.write can't use Array[Byte]()?

Tags: scala

I have this code:

```
val socket=new ServerSocket(25)
val client=socket.accept()
val inputStream=client.getInputStream
var dataBuffer=new Array[Byte](4096)
inputStream.read(dataBuffer)
Files.write("",dataBuffer)
```

Files.write need a Byte array,and I have give it a Byte array,so why I got error at last line:

```
Type mismatch,expected:Iterable[_<:CharSequence],actual:Array[Byte]
```

inputStream.read also need a Byte array param,it can use dataBuffer,so why the next line got a error?How to fix it?Thanks!

Comment: How do you import `Files`?

Comment: import java.nio.file.Files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `java.nio.file.Files` you should use `Path` as first parameter.

```
val b: Array[Byte] = Array()
Files.write(Paths.get(""), b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.net.ServerSocket
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
object Test1 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val socket = new ServerSocket(9999)
    val client = socket.accept()
    val inputStream = client.getInputStream
    var dataBuffer = new Array[Byte](4096)
    inputStream.read(dataBuffer)
    Files.write(Paths.get("/home/eiffel/a.txt"), dataBuffer)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer